# Ordered input attribute for Microsoft Naive Bayes algorithm

Tags: sql-server, data-mining, ssas

Could someone explain me why I get next error message:

> Mining structure column MyColumn has content type of Ordered that is not
>   supported by Microsoft Association or Microsoft Naive Bayes algorithms.

Documentation states that ([Content Types (Data Mining)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174572.aspx)):

> This content type is supported by all the data mining data types in Analysis
>   Services. However, however, most algorithms treat ordered values as
>   discrete values and do not perform special processing.

And specifically for Bayes ([Microsoft Naive Bayes Algorithm Technical Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645902.aspx)):

> Input attribute: Cyclical, Discrete, Discretized, Key, Table, and Ordered

And another question. What algorithms does the Ordered content type have impact on? I mean if we use Ordered instead of just Discrete.

Answer (score 2):

The ORDERED content type has no impact on any of the SSAS algorithm.  It was added to the OLEDB for Data Mining specification in 1999 based on feedback from other data mining vendors.  It is possible to write a custom algorithm that will consider the ORDERED flag, but there is no practical way in SQL Server 2005 and beyond to actually order the actual discrete values (there was a way in SQL Server 2000, but it's not practical for 2005+ and likely doesn't work.)

As an aside, the only time ordered discrete states are considered by any SSAS algorithm is when the Clustering algorithm handles discretized values.